# Docker container exit: segmentation fault, errno 139, exit status 139

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, errno

I am new to the docker thing. I build a docker container called: app in which my webapp is running and a mongodb container called: mongo which provides the data for my webapp.
I use the docker compose to set both containers up.
I have a login screen on my webserver and when i want to log in, my app container crashs.
With following error massage:

```
app      | Segmentation fault (core dumped)
app      | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
app      | npm ERR! errno 139
app      | npm ERR! test@0.0.0 start: `NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www`
app      | npm ERR! Exit status 139
app      | npm ERR!
app      | npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.0.0 start script.
app      | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
app      |
app      | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
app      | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-22T06_49_55_101Z-debug.log
```

My dockerfile looks like the following:

```
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine

ARG NPM_TOKEN

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .npmrc .npmrc
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual native-deps \
 g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python && \
 npm install --quiet node-gyp -g &&\
 npm install --quiet && \
 apk del native-deps

RUN npm install

RUN rm -f .npmrc
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```

and the docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
 app:
   container_name: app
   restart: always
   build: .
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   links:
     - mongo
 mongo:
   container_name: mongo
   image: mongo
   volumes:
     - ./data:/data/db
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
```

When i only start the mongodb container and the app with the command "NODE_ENV=production node ./bin/www" (without container) then everything is working fine...
(I only change the mongo db "host" name when i run the app local or in a container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually no idea what I am doing, but when I change my dockerfile like this it is working:

```
FROM node:8.11.3-alpine
ARG NPM_TOKEN

RUN apk update

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .npmrc .npmrc

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python

RUN npm config set python /usr/bin/python
RUN npm i -g npm
RUN npm install
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
RUN apk del builds-deps
RUN rm -f .npmrc

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start"]
```